# How to run a python script from C# window?

Tags: python, c#

The python script is:

```py
import time

for i in range(200):
   print("hey")
```

How can I run such a simple script from my C# console application?

I'm not trying to covert it over into C#. I want to actually run this python script from my C# program application.

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? `for(var i=0; i<200; i++) Console.WriteLine("Hey");`

Comment: Yeah but the thing is, im not trying to covert it over into C#. I want to actually run this the .py version from my C# program application

Comment: You would run it like you would any other external program, which in this case would be the path locally installed Python interpreter being passed an argument that's the path to Python script.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for(var i=0; i<200; i++) Console.WriteLine("Hey");
```

Credit @Micheal Randall

Comment: Yeah but the thing is, im not trying to covert it over into C#. I want to actually run this the .py version from my C# program application

Answer (score 1):

I will System.Diagnostics.Process for this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MySpace {
  public class MyProgram {
    public static void Main(string[] args){
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Python27\python.exe", @"FILEPATH")
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };
    p.Start();
    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    p.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}}}
```

This will print the result of the python program to c# console

Comment: I really appreciate this answer. I will test it out now. Thanks brother

Comment: Hey. This solution worked for my question. However, when I changed my code to this, 

import pyautogui

for i in range(200):
   print("hey")
   pyautogui.scroll(-132)


The "hey" doesn't display 200 times like before. Do you know what issue does this pertain to?

Comment: You are scrolling backwards? (I am not so efficient in PyAutoGUI)